# Dart: How to convert Uint8List to Buffer?

Tags: flutter, dart, buffer, uint8list

Here is the Uint8List which look like 
`[92, 37, 74, 216, 114, 178, 220, 105, 117, 200, 131, 83, 238, 62, 121, 82, 12, 176, 88, 217, 100, 37, 189, 98, 155, 103, 217, 37, 45, 213, 143, 135]`. 
This I have to convert to Buffer which looks like 
`<Buffer 49 27 6d 20 61 20 73 74 72 69 6e 67 21>` In Dart.

I tried out multiple ways I did not get the proper result. Help!

Comment: What do these represent? Is one a hash? Is the longer one encrypted?

Comment: It isn't  encrypted I just need to convert it

Comment: The shorter one is a string, but what does the longer one represent?

Comment: `Sodium.cryptoSignSeedKeypair(seedLength32).then((value) {
      var sk = value['sk'];
      var pk = value['pk'];
      print("VALUE['sk'] ===> $sk");
      print("VALUE['pk'] ===> $pk");}` For this function You get the above Uint8List that data **pk** I have to change it to buffer.

Comment: If I print this `pk.buffer` then I get the output as **Instance of '_ByteBuffer'**

Comment: And also I tried this `pk.buffer.asByteData()` then I get the output as**TypedDataView(cid: 148)**

Comment: As you note `.buffer` returns a `ByteBuffer`. Is that what you want? If not, what? Where do you want to use the result?

Comment: Yeah, You are right. If I print this `pk.buffer` then I get the output as **Instance of '_ByteBuffer'**, How do I see the data? I get the instance of ByteBuffer instead I need the output as I mentioned above in the question.

Comment: You need to explain how you want to use it. Your example about shows an ASCII string saying "I'm a string" that's not really useful as a public key! The data in the buffer is identical to the data in the list, but doesn't have a tostring to print it.

Comment: Is your question about converting the data to hexadecimal?

Comment: As I was looking at it I found that Uint8List and Buffer are same, I used hex.encode() and hex.decode() to convert to string | to buffer and vise-versa

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that Uint8List is the same as Buffer.In **JS** we used to get the buffer as in this format <Buffer 10,21, 220, ..., 90>. In **Dart** we something it looks like [10,21, 220, ..., 90]